# Combine Tables / Join Query MySql

Tags: mysql, sql, join

I am stuck with this query and I am not able to solve it. I need help in joining tables.

I have 4 tables (customer, product, status and offer).

I want to read from these tables based on customer ID.

In first 3 tables, the number of record against customer ID is one, but offer table may have more than one rows for a customer.

I want to read the latest row from the offer table for each customer. I am not able make a query for this situation.

For example

```
Customer have columns (cID, Name, Surname)
STATUS (sID, cID, Status, Sdate)
ADDRESS (adID, cID, Addetail)
Offer (ID, cID, offer, offDate)
```

Here is my query, which is not working:

```
SELECT c.ID, 
c.NAME, 
c.SURNAME, 
st.ID, 
st.Status, 
st.Sdate
ad.Addetial,
off.OffDATE
FROM customer c, address ad, status st, offer of

WHERE 
c.ID=ad.cID 
AND c.ID=st.cID 
AND c.ID = off.cID
..
```

I am confuse how to restrict the selection to one row from the offer table. because if I put c.ID = off.cID then it will return all the offers which I don't want.

PS: I know there are similar questions, but I couldn't map it according to my situation. 
Using Max, returns only one row (even if there are many customers).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this one

```
SELECT c.ID, 
c.NAME, 
c.SURNAME, 
st.ID, 
st.Status, 
st.Sdate
ad.Addetial,
off.OffDATE
FROM customer c   
WHERE 
INNER JOIN  address ad ON c.ID=ad.cID 
INNER JOIN  status st  ON AND c.ID=st.cID 
INNER JOIN (SELECT *,MAX(id) AS `max` FROM offer GROUP BY  id ,cID) off
ON c.ID = off.cID
```

I have used  a subquery `(SELECT *,MAX(id) AS max FROM offer GROUP BY  id ,cID)` to get the latest customer offers subquery will  execute only once to get the desired latest dataset

Answer (score 0):

You want the [groupwise maximum](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/en/example-maximum-column-group-row.html), which can be obtained by joining the `offer` table to a grouped version of itself:

```sql
SELECT c.ID,
       c.NAME, 
       c.SURNAME, 
       st.ID, 
       st.Status, 
       st.Sdate
       ad.Addetial,
       off.OffDATE
FROM   customer c
  JOIN address  ad ON ad.cID = c.ID
  JOIN status   st ON st.cID = c.ID
  JOIN (offer  off NATURAL JOIN (
         SELECT   cID, MAX(OffDATE) OffDATE
         FROM     offer
         GROUP BY cID
       ) t) ON off.cID = c.ID
```